# Change TableName in ADOTable on button click

Tags: c++, ms-access, button, ado, c++builder-xe2

I have a DataBase, made in MS Access, which contains 2 tables. Table #1 is displayed in DBGrid. I want table #2 to be displayed in DBGrid on button click. 
Thought it would be smth like:
`ADOTable1->TableName = table_n2`, but I was wrong.
Does anybody knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

That should work, just make sure you set ADOTable1->Active = false; then do that and then set it back to true.  Or possibly use ADOTable1->Refresh();

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will check if this works.
I tryed to use ADOQuery instead of ADOTable and it worked.
Here is code `ADOQuery->Active=false;
  ADOQuery->SQL->Clear();
  ADOQuery->SQL->Add("SELECT * From table_n2");
  ADOQuery->Active=true;`

Comment: Yeah, basically you are doing the same thing there, it is all about refreshing the information to your datasource component that is tied to the grid.  Otherwise it is still looking at the memory of the old statement.